# test then or success of $http request with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I would like to test with jasmine the success of this $http request on an event listener in a directive :

```
$rootScope.$on('save', function () {
        var id = $scope.instance.id;
        $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: MY_API + "/containerInstance/" + id,
            withCredentials: true,
            data: mydata
        }).success(function () {
            $scope.success = true;
        });
    }));
```

But i don't how i can do that, i try this :

```
    it('Event save', function(){
        var successCallback = jasmine.createSpy();
        $scope.instance = data;

        $httpBackend.expectPUT(MY_API + "/containerInstance/1").respond(200, 'mock data');
        expect(successCallback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        $rootScope.$broadcast('save');
        $httpBackend.flush();

    });
```

But I have error message Unexpected request: GET MY_API/page/1
    Expected PUT MY_API/containerInstance/1

I don't know why he try to go to 'MY_API/page/1' (it's another url in my API)

Can you help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: can you put more code? In some place of the test startup  'MY_API/page/1' is being called.

Comment: ^^^ This is very common, your controller or whatever is triggering some other code that is making the request before it gets to the actual code that is being tested. An easy way to solve it is to add an expectation for such URLs in your test. Another way would be to structure your code so that the functionality your testing is decoupled from the startup code.

Comment: Thx Sunil, I have played the first query expected : Unexpected request: GET MY_API/page/1 Expected PUT before my $httbackend request and it works.
I think in my project the MY_API + "/containerInstance/1" url need MY_API/page/1 url before.

Thank ou very much.